# Best practice to combine JS files

Tags: javascript

I always have this questions in mind come to JS optimise, nowadays most people combine all their CSSs into single file by using Less, Sass or others methods. but come to JS i am a bit hesitate on the approach, cause there are plug-in, frameworks and your own code. Just wondering is there a rule or best practice to approach.

so should i combine all my JSs into single JS include plug-in, frameworks, libary and my own code into one or keep them modularized accordingly.

I know it may depend on the size of the project, but what's the measurement and when I should combine all into one or modularize. Is there any rules I should be followed.

Any suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: Combine and minify in the order in the order they are dependent on.  The framework would be the top most file

Comment: ok your approach is combine everything into one, I use Requrie.js it can combine everything into one. Will combined size be a concern? I know probably gzip will help while transfer the file. (My combine(eveything) would probably up to about 400-500k)

Comment: If your js files are too large to transfer, you're doing something seriously wrong.

Comment: The entire jquery library, which is over 10,000 lines last time I checked, is only 276 KB. As long as your under several MB, you should be good.

Comment: @JamesG. ok fair point, looks like most ppl decide to combine all files.

Comment: you could also load Just In Time, so if the user clicks the search box, load the auto complete module. Make it fast by making sure your HTTP cache is set up correctly causing the browser not to re-download the file (301)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to combine and minify your own development JavaScript. Having multiple HTTP requests can slow down load times if there are too many requests (especially if there are multiple small files). Google PageSpeed Insights gives some guidelines on how to do it [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources).

As [@veroxii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2172360/veroxii) says, most people end up using a "build" since minifying and combining everything manually would be a huge waste of time. For small sites that I work on that don't really have a built in minification system, I like to use [gulpjs](http://gulpjs.com/) along with [gulp-uglify](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify) and [gulp-concat](https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-concat) to minify and combine javascript resources.

You have to be careful when combining though because often times, scripts will depend on other scripts. Say you have two scripts that you combined where scriptB depends on scriptA. If the browser loads and runs scriptB before scriptA because it came first in the combined file, then bad things will happen. Either be careful with your script combination or use something like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).

You can't really do much in terms of minification or combination when using a third party script loaded in from a CDN (like jQuery) except use the production script.min.js resource that they provide. You could potentially download their script and throw it into your minification process, but most users are more likely to already have the CDN version cached by their browser.

The biggest thing when it comes to JavaScript is making sure the loading of the scripts don't block the rendering of the page. Most JavaScript is useless without content, so why not let the content load first and then load in the script? Users will see the content first and then interact so it's probably a good idea to load those resources in that order. [More on that here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS). Either put your script tags at the bottom of the page, use the `async`attribute, or use an asynchronous javascript loader like [loadJS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadJS) or requirejs.

Answer (score 2):

Which framework are you using on the server side? Most of the frameworks out there come with an "asset pipeline" already built in or as a plugin.

For instance django has https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ and grails has http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline

This does everything you asked about and more. I'm sure there's something similar for whatever you're using on the serving back-end.

Edit: to clarify - I don't think this is something people do manually. They have a tool which does it on the fly or at build/deploy time.